# How to check if one string contains another case insensitively?

Tags: vb.net

```
  comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
  Console.WriteLine("   {0:G}: {1}", comp, s.Contains(sub1, comp))
```

That seems like the way. However, I tried and it doesn't work. It seems that the only altenative of s.Contains take char() as first argument. If I want to insert string as first argument then I cannot have second argument as **StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase.**

I got the snippet from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can use IndexOf function.

```
Console.WriteLine(s.IndexOf(sub1, 0, StringComparison. OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)
```

Above snippet prints true or false depending on whether s contains sub1.

Alternatively, if you want to use contains, you can use ToUpper or ToLower as shown below...

```
Console.WriteLine("   {0:G}: {1}", comp, s.ToUpper().Contains(sub1.ToUpper()))
```

The link you gave in question shows you how to create a custom extension to string. He also gave the code you have to use to create that custom extension and that method uses IndexOf internally if you had observed.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224424.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Hmmm but microsoft sample says we can use string.contains.

Comment: @JimThio No, it says "you can create a custom method..."

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(sub1.ToLowerInvariant())
```

The link you pointed to in your question defines the follow extension method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module StringExtensions
   <Extension()>
   Public Function Contains(str As String, substring As String, 
                            comp As StringComparison) As Boolean
      If substring Is Nothing Then
         Throw New ArgumentNullException("substring", 
                                         "substring cannot be null.")
      Else If Not [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(StringComparison), comp)
         Throw New ArgumentException("comp is not a member of StringComparison",
                                     "comp")
      End If                               
      Return str.IndexOf(substring, comp) >= 0                      
   End Function
End Module
```

Unless you implement this your call to `s.Contains(sub1, comp)` won't work.

Comment: By the way, those tests are really redundant, because `IndexOf` already throws the same exceptions when the arguments are bad. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx